# PHP - MYSQL Stored Procedure Out Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql stored procedure that takes 3 parameters - 2 In and 1 out
I am calling this procedure from php using mysqli

The procedure will return 1 row and I use the following code when calling it

```
    $result = $mysqli->query("call get_hybrid_auth_session('".$userId."','".$loginSystem."', @hybridAuthSession)");
    $result = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT @hybridAuthSession' );
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
```

When I do a var_dump on the $row attribute, I get the following text back

```
object(stdClass)#16 (1) { ["@hybridAuthSession"]=> string(287) ".a:3:{s:40:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token";s:56:"s:48:"23801232-fkv05uitVRobpItrFFUn15I4Ejl0w80pr7GOH0A";";s:47:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token_secret";s:51:"s:43:"VKsFaQWnP8n9OcZK3MDCgRHQY0roLTFVXesBuONCYJo";";s:34:"hauth_session.twitter.is_logged_in";s:4:"i:1;";}." }
```

When I do a var_dump on the $row->{"@hybridAuthSession"} attribute, I get the following value back

```
string(287) ".a:3:{s:40:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token";s:56:"s:48:"23801232-fkv05uitVRobpItrFFUn15I4Ejl0w80pr7GOH0A";";s:47:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token_secret";s:51:"s:43:"VKsFaQWnP8n9OcZK3MDCgRHQY0roLTFVXesBuONCYJo";";s:34:"hauth_session.twitter.is_logged_in";s:4:"i:1;";}."
```

Is there any way to not receive the string(287) value at the start?
The hybridAuthSession Out parameter is defined as Text in my stored procedure

Comment: that value is not really there, just shows for the var_dump to describe the return.  it is not part of the return.

Comment: That string(287) value isn't actually there. That's just var_dump telling you the type and length.

Comment: oops sorry guys, yes it showed up there correctly and is working as expected. Just moving from Java to Php at the minute and getting up to speed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var dump was adding additional information when outputting the text to the screen which is its expected behaviour.
After some more tests, the code was working as expected